# Flake8 not using pyflakes in global python instance

Tags: python, pyflakes, flake8

My pyflakes portion of flake8 is not running for my global python instance (`/usr/bin/python`, not virtualenv).

```
flake8 --version
2.2.3 (pep8: 1.5.7, mccabe: 0.2.1) CPython 2.7.5 on Darwin
```

It doesn't seem like pyflakes is getting attached to flake8. `pip freeze` confirms that `pyflakes==0.8.1` is installed. I installed on my global site-packages (`$ sudo pip install flake8`).

However, when running inside of a virtualenv, pyflakes is in the list and flake8 works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem with conda's flake8. Here are some debugging notes:

flake8 registers the pyflakes checker in its `setup.py` file:

```
setup(
...
    entry_points={
        'distutils.commands': ['flake8 = flake8.main:Flake8Command'],
        'console_scripts': ['flake8 = flake8.main:main'],
        'flake8.extension': [
            'F = flake8._pyflakes:FlakesChecker',
        ],
    },
...
```

When checking a file, flake8 loads the registered entry points for 'flake8.extension' and registers found checkers:

```
...
for entry in iter_entry_points('flake8.extension'):
    checker = entry.load()
    pep8.register_check(checker, codes=[entry.name])
...
```

conda's flake8 seems to have problems writing those entry points.

```
from pkg_resources import iter_entry_points
list(iter_entry_points('flake8.extension'))
```

returns an empty list for me, which is why pyflakes won't be registered and thus does not work, even though it is installed and importable.

Updating setuptools and installing via `pip install flake8` fixes the problem for me.

Comment: i'm facing the same problem, but i'm not too sure what do you mean by "Update setuptools", can you be a little more specific?

Comment: @RobertoAguilar, that depends. This bug is fixed in newer versions of `anaconda`. If you are using `anaconda`, you can just type `conda update flake8`. If you are using vanilla python, you would go with `pip install --upgrade setuptools`, then `pip install --upgrade flake8`

Comment: I have tried the pip commands and now flake8 is calling pyflakes successfully, thank you very much